# Variable change in controller not being reflected on UI - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am changing a variable in my controller by calling a function. The variable 
isSameTaxonomyElements is bind with an element in UI. But it is being reflected on UI.

```
$scope.validateAddElementButton = function (name, label) {          
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.elements.length; i++) {             
                if (name === $scope.elements[i].name || label === $scope.elements[i].label) {
                  $scope.isSameTaxonomyElements = true;      
                  break; 
                } else {
                  $scope.isSameTaxonomyElements = false;                
                }             
            }          
        }
```

This is my UI.

```
 <div ng-show="isSameTaxonomyElements">
                <div class="col-lg-6 float-left" >
                  <p class="alert-message">No two elements should have same label or name.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I have also tried adding $timeout, $apply etc, but still not working.

Comment: could you post more code ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JavaScript variable will take only last assigned value. So according to your code, in side that for loop, if the condition is satisfied, `isSameTaxonomyElements` will be `true` and your loop breaks (i.e. no more loop); or else `isSameTaxonomyElements` will be `false`, and eventually `isSameTaxonomyElements` will be `false` if the loop doesn't early exit.

And check basic things like controller name, app name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable isn't in controller scope. add new html page and add new controller also then create a new route. test your function in added new controller.
second: check scope id in old controller. i think your html not in controller scope.